# Views do not rotate correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view, orientation

I use an IF statement to detect when the orientation of a device changes, and when it does, a new view is displayed, one portrait, the other landscape. The only problem is, if I rotate from portrait to landscape, and the landscape view shows, it has not rotated all of the way. It is still in portrait, 90 degrees off of what it should be. Thanks for your help!

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        //portrait

        self.view = portrait;


    } else {
        //landscape

        self.view = landscape;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sample code provided by Apple for this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AlternateViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008755).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix it by storing the destination orientation during willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, then pushing your new view afterwards on didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: Ok, so how would I do that? Something similar to self.view = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, etc? Thanks for your help!